# Continuous Azure WebJob with Http Triggered Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I currently have an azure webjob that performs a daily sync from one database to another, but would like to add the ability to manually trigger the sync as well. I have set up the functions as follows in the webjob project:

```
public static void SyncData([TimerTrigger("0 0 5 * * *", RunOnStartup = false)] TimerInfo timerInfo) { }

[NoAutomaticTrigger]
public static Task SyncAll(TraceWriter log){ }
[NoAutomaticTrigger]
public static Task SyncBranches(TraceWriter log){ }
[NoAutomaticTrigger]
public static Task SyncCustomers(TraceWriter log){ }
[NoAutomaticTrigger]
public static Task SyncInventory(TraceWriter log){ }
```

I can see the functions in the Kudu dashboard under the webjob, but am not sure how I can trigger the functions with an http request as listed on the MS documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook)):

```
http://<yourapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/<funcname>
```

When I make a request to that endpoint I get a 404 response - what do I need to do in order to trigger those functions manually via http request?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use the Kudu [WebJob API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API) to start or stop a continuous job

> POST https://{user}:{password}@{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs/{job name}/start

We can get user and password info from the Azure WebApp publishSetting file. And We can download the file from the portal

[image]

Test the Rest API using the fiddler

[image]

**Note**: How to create Azure function please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function).

**Update:**

> is there a way I can trigger a specific function in that continuous job?

Based on my experience, I can't find a way or Rest API to trigger a sepcific function in continuous job directly.

My work around is that we can use Webjob QueueTrigger. According the queue message info to trigger the sepcific function.
We can create a [WebJob with QueueTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to)

The following is my detail steps according to your code.

1.Create an Azure storage queue for trigger

[image]

2.Create a Webjob project and add the following code

```
 public static void SyncData([QueueTrigger("backup")] string logMessage, TextWriter logger)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Start time:{DateTime.Now}");
        switch (logMessage.ToLower())
        {
            case "syncall":
                SyncAll(logger);
                break;
            case "syncbranches":
                SyncBranches(logger);
                break;
            case "synccustomers":
                SyncCustomers(logger);
                break;
            case "syncinventory":
                SyncInventory(logger);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                break;
        }
        Console.Write($"Endtime:{DateTime.Now}");

    }
    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public static Task SyncAll(TextWriter log)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("SyncAll :"+DateTime.Now);
        return null;
        //await Task.Delay(10);
    }

    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public static Task SyncBranches(TextWriter log)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SyncBranches :" + DateTime.Now);
        return null;
    }

    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public static Task SyncCustomers(TextWriter log)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SyncCustomers :" + DateTime.Now);
        return null;
    }

    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public static Task SyncInventory(TextWriter log)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SyncInventory :" + DateTime.Now);
        return null;
    }
```

3.Use Azure [Storage Queue REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-message) to create a queue message.

4.Check result the from the console.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom - is there a way I can trigger a specific function in that continuous job? Stopping and starting the current job would not run any of the functions - it would just have the scheduled function wait for the scheduled time correct?

Comment: If you want to trigger the sepcific function in the azure webjob, my walk-around is using queue trigger. More detail I have updated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the doc for Azure Functions but it looks like you're using WebJobs (which is different from Azure Functions).

I suggest using Azure Functions instead, in which case your scenario becomes more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

when you have

```
SyncData([TimerTrigger("0 0 5 * * *", RunOnStartup = false)]
```

it is the continuous job, which IMHO is not optimal, you could change it to really running on schedule (meaning it will not consume resources when it's idle), then you could run it simply from UI
[image: steps to run manually]
For this you have to remove timer trigger:

```
public static void SyncData() { }
```

Schedule in this case provided in Settings.job text file in the root of your WebJob project, with content:

```
{
  "schedule": "0 0 5 * * *",
  "is_singleton": true
}
```

And also adjust a bit Program.cs:

```
//now it will start your functions manually
var host = builder.Build();
using (host)
{
  var functions = host.Services.GetService(typeof(Functions)) as Functions;
  //in my case it is Run method, but I guess you have there SyncData
  await functions.Run();
}
//when it was continious
//var host = builder.Build();
//using (host)
//{
//    await host.RunAsync(ct);
//    tokenSource.Dispose();
//}
```

You also need to make your job type of triggered, republish it and remove old Continuous one.